# How can I add an Access DB to my C# project when it requires an MDW file too?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I want to use an Access database file in my C# project. When I add it as a new Data Source all goes well until I try to test the connection. Then I get the message:

```
Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.
```

The file is password protected and an MDW file is used. So how can I add the file as a data source and use the workgroup info file as well?

Thanks

Comment: What is your connection string? The MDW location can be specified there.

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\newUser_be.mdb;User ID="Jim"   But it wont let me edit the connection string. Unless its done some other way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example connection string specifying where the .MDW file is located:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;
    Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Thanks RedFilter! That was what I needed/