# Migration Windows app using C# .net from network server to local desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I developed a windows application using C# in .net framework and published using clickonce deployment on network server. There were multiple users and worked successfully. It has been using MS Access 2003 as backend. The problem is network server is being shut down soon. Hence, I moved the application and the database to a local computer and published again using click once deployment. Anytime a user tries to open the application, the message pops up that application cannot be downloaded. The workgroup information is missing or opened exclusively by another user.

None of the set up changed except, that it is on local drive on a desktop. There is no chance that anyone tries open the database. Please help. I am stuck...

Below is the connection string as well. The mdw file and mdb file are in the same folder on local drive

Thank you!

I tried including Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password. It did not help too

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648853/how-can-i-add-an-access-db-to-my-c-sharp-project-when-it-requires-an-mdw-file-to,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119986/how-to-use-an-mdw-file-in-access-2010, https://www.engram9.info/access-2007-vba/creating-an-mdw-file-1.html and https://www.techonthenet.com/access/security/use_mdw.php

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have already created the .mdw file and it is linked. I don't know why it is still saying workgroup information is missing.